# Advantage computed the wrong way?

Tags: python, policy-gradients, pytorch, actor-critic-methods

Here is the [code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/master/Chapter10/02_pong_a2c.py) written by Maxim Lapan. I am reading his book (*Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-on*). I have seen a line in his code which is really weird. In the accumulation of the policy gradient $$\partial \theta_{\pi} \gets \partial \theta_{\pi} + \nabla_{\theta}\log\pi_{\theta} (a_i | s_i) (R - V_{\theta}(s_i))$$ we have to compute the advantage $R - V_{\theta}(s_i)$. In line 138, maxim uses `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.detach()`. Visually, it looks fine, but look at the shape of each term.

```
ipdb> adv_v.shape                                                                                                                            
torch.Size([128, 128])

ipdb> vals_ref_v.shape                                                                                                                       
torch.Size([128])

ipdb> values_v.detach().shape                                                                                                                
torch.Size([128, 1])
```

In a much simpler code, it is equivalent to

```
In [1]: import torch                                                            

In [2]: t1 = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])                                            

In [3]: t2 = torch.tensor([[4], [5], [6]])                                      

In [4]: t1 - t2                                                                 
Out[4]: 
tensor([[-3, -2, -1],
        [-4, -3, -2],
        [-5, -4, -3]])

In [5]: t1 - t2.detach()                                                        
Out[5]: 
tensor([[-3, -2, -1],
        [-4, -3, -2],
        [-5, -4, -3]])
```

I have trained the agent with his code and it works perfectly fine. I am very confused why it is good practice and what it is doing. Could someone enlighten me on the line `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.detach()`? For me, the right thing to do was `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.squeeze(-1)`.

Here is the full algorithm used in his book :

**UPDATE**

[image]

As you can see by the image, it is converging even though `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.detach()` looks wrongly implemented. It is not done yet, but I will update the question later.

Comment: Could you clarify, you trained the agent with his code or with your modified code? If both, did you notice any difference in behaviour?

Comment: @dan888 With his code. I just cloned the repo.

Comment: That's interesting. I would say that what you are doing would make more sense as well. I noticed you created an issue on github, I'm curious to see what comes out of that.

Comment: He used the same line many times in his book, but I can't say why it is working and what it is doing exactly. I am going to update the question in few hours to add a graph of what the mean rewards look like. In his book, maxim said *The call to `value_v.detach()` is important, as we don't want to propagate the PG into our value approximation head*. That didn't help me, but maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it seems like it's a wrong implementation.
vals_ref_v is a matrix of 1 row, and 128 columns.
value_v.detach() is a matrix of 128 row

Comment: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/issues/74

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.detach()` to `adv_v = vals_ref_v - value_v.squeeze(-1).detach()`. It seems the convergence is much faster. According to the A2C algorithm, it is just logic to apply $Q(a, s) - V(s)$, where $Q(a, s)$ and $V(s)$ with the same shape.

The call to `detach()` is important here as we don't want to propagate the PG into our value approximation head.